# Image popping up instead of displaying in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, image, opencv

This is the code below I used to display an image using the opencv library in Jupyter notebook. But instead of the displaying the image inside the jupyter notebook. An image window is popping up.
Is there any command to solve this problem.
check my code below

````
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("squirrel.jpg")

cv2.imshow("squirrel",image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()```
````

Comment: Use matplotlib for display. I don’t think you’ll ever manage to corral OpenCV’s display window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image = mpimg.imread('squirrel.jpg')
plt.imshow(image)
```

Comment: Alex it really helped me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Great news. If it solved your problem, I think you can mark the question as solved.